# How to prevent the generating of __IO_putc?

Tags: c++, c, linux, glibc

When I `objdump` my a.out, I found that `__IO_putc` were used.

I know that gcc would use `putc` to replace `printf` when input of `printf` is simple. But why gcc replace my `putc` into `__IO_putc`? Can I prevent this replacement by using some command line like `-U_FORTYFY`(which disables `__printf_chk`) or `--fno-stack-protector`(which disables __stack_chk_fail)?

Comment: Any reason you don't want these symbols in your binary?

Comment: __IO_putc is a glibc internal function, but this function makes trouble when I want to do something like cross compilation or binary translation.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent the "replace `printf` with `putc`"?

Comment: Please explain in detail why you don't want that in your answer.

Comment: @hwliu Your binary is at any rate dependent on the ABI of glibc, you've generated code that embeds a ton of structures and types that are specific to glibc, so only caring about a particular glibc symbol might not  help you that much

Answer (score 4):

> why gcc replace my `putc` into `__IO_putc`

In your `/usr/include/stdio.h`, you will find this line:

```
#define putc(_ch, _fp) _IO_putc (_ch, _fp)
```

> Can I prevent this replacement by using some command line

You could put `#undef putc` into your source after `#include <stdio.h>`, or enclose the function name in parenthesis at each call site, like so:

```
(putc)('a', stdout);
```

In general, you should *not* mess with standard functions like this one.

Comment: Actually, `#undef putc` is perfectly legal (see section 7.1.4 of the C standard). *Redefining* it would not be. I prefer the use of parentheses to avoid expansion, because it does not have global effect, but in this case that probably doesn't matter and both options are explicitly allowed by the standard.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can always avoid expansion of function-like macros by parenthesizing the name:

```
(putc)('c', outfile);
```

This is specifically permitted by the C standard, in §7.1.4 ("Use of library functions") (emphasis added):

> Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined in the header, so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by such a macro. **Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing
>   the name of the function in parentheses**, because the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates expansion of a macro function name.

In the particular case of the standard library implementation bundled with gcc, you will probably find that using `fputc` instead of `putc` results in an actual call to `fputc`. (The standard requires the underlying functionality of `fputc` to be identical to `putc`; it allows a macro implementation of `putc` -- if there is one -- to evaluate the second argument more than once.)

---

For what it's worth, I checked using gcc 5.2.0 and it appears that `fprintf` is translated to a call to `fputc`, not `putc`. An explicit invocation of `putc` is indeed macro expanded to a call to `__IO_putc`, but this can be avoided as above.

Sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  FILE* outfile = stdout;
  fprintf(outfile, "c");
  putc('c', outfile);
  (putc)('c', outfile);
  return 0;
}
```

Generated code (comments added):

```
main:
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    stdout(%rip), %rbx
    movl    $99, %edi
    movq    %rbx, %rsi
    call    fputc          # fprintf(outfile, "c")
    movq    %rbx, %rsi
    movl    $99, %edi
    call    _IO_putc       # putc('c', outfile)
    movq    %rbx, %rsi
    movl    $99, %edi
    call    putc           # (putc)('c', outfile);
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

`putc` is translated into `__IO_putc` during the preprocessing phase, due to the expansion of macros from `<stdio.h>`.  You can indeed try to prevent this by using `fputc` or hacking the header file or `#undef`ining `putc` after the `#include <stdio.h>`, but this is not the correct fix, you are just lucky if it works, and more problems will arise later, as you rely on more library features.

`gcc` is configured to compile for a given target, with a combination of configuration options and a set of header files and libraries.  It is important to understand that the header files are intrinsically linked to the corresponding libraries for each specific version.  You cannot just compile with a *generic* `<stdio.h>` header file and expect to link with the C library for another target.  Cross-compiling requires correct configuration of the complete tool-chain.  If you have a specific versions of the C library you want to link to, use the header files that come with it.

OTOH, if you just want source files to use your version of the standard I/O functions, just preventing the expansion and linking with your library first might do the job. An alternative is to redefine `putc` and all the other functions you want to replace, replacing all calls to calls to your replacements, but you are still messing with standard library identifiers, so anything can happen.

Comment: Redefining a standard library name is undefined behaviour. &sect;7.1.3. Just sayin'.

Comment: @rici: Interesting! actually, according to C11 7.1.3, both `#undef`ining and `#define`ing `putc` are deemed to invoke undefined behaviour.  I edited my answer to not encourage such contorsions.

Comment: As I read it, 7.1.3 says that `#undef` of a library name produces undefined behaviour unless specifically allowed in 7.1.4, which in this case it is.

Comment: @rici: in n1570, 7.1.3, *If the program removes (with #undef) any macro definition of an identifier in the first group listed above, the behavior is undefined.*. I don't see any exclusion from this principle.  Section 7.1.4 indeed documents #undef for this case, in contradiction with the previous paragraph and without an explicit exception.  This looks like a bug in the Standard. Unless I am looking at a draft and the language was changed in the final version.

Comment: @rici: I got it, the first goup refers not to the enumeration of the first paragraph, but just the first item of the enumeration.  You are correct.  I amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat different approach from me:

If you are replacing standard library functions with your own library version. you probably want to write your own version of "stdio.h", not use the one that comes with the compiler. Or, if you are using the one that the compiler provides, you probably want to implement the low-level IO-functionst hat it actually uses, rather than replacing the higher level functions (in other words, figure out what `__IO_putc` actually does, and replace whatever that is, etc).

To "mess" with the content of standard headers by doing `#undef` or similar in your code is likely to insert new problems elsewhere, and very likely to cause problems if you ever want to import a large project of someone else's code. If, instead, you have your own version of "stdio.h", that simply doesn't do the `#define putc ...` in the first place, then you have no problem that needs to be resolved later - and as long as you do everything the external product needs, it'll just work.

It is important to understand that the "stdio.h" and it's friends are paired with a certain C runtime library (in combination with a certain compiler in most cases), so if you are replacing the C runtime library, then you should also replace the corresponding header-file with one that works for the library (and the compiler of your choice)

Comment: Technically, you need to replace **all** library functions that use the `FILE` structure, or at least recompile the ones you do not replace with your new version.  Both require advanced mastery of the language and its libraries.

Comment: Yes, and unless you actually support all of them, including a header-file that has prototypes for of them is just folly, since they won't work unless either the platform is 100% compatible (in which case nothing needs to be done, and this question wouldn't exist) or they are implemented. Hence my suggestion for having your own header-file. This in particular if you only support a subset!

Comment: I'm afraid that's not enough, because a real life standard library such as glibc contains a lot of functions that use stdio.h beyond the standard ones. So redefining them all is hopeless and redefining just a subset that will be linked in place of the library's own may create inconsistencies with dire consequences.  `#define`ing a subset to refer to user defined wrappers is actually less risky.

Comment: Not sure I get your point. Say I implement my own printf, putc and scanf. Having a header-file that declared `fprintf`, `fgets` and 140 other functions that glibc provides will not HELP, since they are not available on my platform. So what problem does it solve that all manner of glibc functions use stdio.h? Or do you believe the OP _just_ want to replace `printf` and `putc`, and not one single other function?

Comment: Its not clear what the OP really intends to do.  If he wants to trace calls to that standard I/O functions, compiling his program with a set of macros that implement a layer on top on the stdio.h functions is safer than attempting to change them at link time by linking to a specific object file.

Comment: Redefining some of the stdio functions is one thing, changing the implementation of the `FILE` structure has much more far reaching consequences.

Comment: OP mentions two things: "something like cross compilation or binary translation" - the former, to me requires implementing a more or less complete C-library, and a new header (including your own FILE structure, I suspect - at least the times I've done this, which isn't many or recently). The latter, since it's binary translation, probably requires understanding that `putc` translates to `__IO_putc` in the first place.

Comment: I agree, no matter what he is really looking for, not understanding basic preprocessor behavior is an indication of the difficulties he is facing. #undef putc is a quick fix that seems to fit his needs.  Maybe he is just interested in making sense of the assembly output... simplifying the translation definitely helps for that.